# How to show search result positions on scroll bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

Chrome shows positions of results from "Find in this page" on the scroll bar (see the orange lines on the scrollbar on the right).  How can I enable the same feature in Firefox (72.0.2)?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's now possible in Firefox 87.

However: it only works for web pages and [not for PDFs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259640#c69), unlike in Chromium Edge for example.

References:

- [Firefox 87.0 release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/87.0/releasenotes/#note-788594)

> The “Highlight All” feature on Find in Page now displays tick marks alongside your scrollbar that correspond to the location of matches found on that page.

- [ghacks article](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/02/14/firefox-87-find-on-page-highlights-matches-in-scrollbar/)
- [Firefox bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259640#c53)

> Thought it might be fun to implement this during the break. With the above patches, the tick marks are drawn in a window's scrollbar using the highlight colour which defaults to something magenta-like. **Note that the 'Highlight All' toggle on the findbar needs to be on for the tick marks to appear**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [HighlightAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/highlightall/) extension. Go to about:addons and choose `Custom highlighting` and `Show search markers`. Then visit any page and make a selection (e.g. by double clicking a word). This is not the same as in Chrome, but should cover many use cases.

[image]

The license is GNU GPL 3.0
There is no public source code repository, but the source code can be inspected by extracting the xpi, as it's a zip file. Fortunately,  the core add-on and libraries source files are well-organized and not minimized.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not open source and requires permission to read data on all websites :(

Comment: That is very unfortunate indeed. I didn't even check for that. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

[final edit, 2022]: As already highlighted in the correct answer, FF has this feature built in since V87.
DEPRECATED INFO:
[highlightall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/highlightall) was until FF V87 the only tool that had the extension .

It still required the some access rights:

- Access your data for all websites
- Read the text of all open tabs
- Display notifications to you

[all other information deleted, as obsolete]
highlightall still "highlights all" occurences of a text passage on a webpage... but that is an answer to a different question

Comment: You say it is open source - where's the code?

Comment: @Will: so, I checked firefoxes profile subfolders again. As all user's profile data [- see here -](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)
the extensions/ folder contains this plugins data. 
In my case the plugin is under "{26FD1F83-A45B-4c74-AF5A-F2EE0EE4D691}.xpi". extracting this shows all parts of the plugin. Extracted it with 7z and took a look.
I am no expert on FF extensions, but looks like Javascript does all the work. There's the sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enable this feature in Firefox (58.0.1).

But if you're willing, you can do this with extensions. I believe there exists extensions that can do this. However I have not tested such extensions.